# Error in allocating value to a cell in R

Tags: r

I am trying to change the value of one cell in a dataframe by providing row and column name from a different dataframe.

I am able to store the value in a variable, but not able to assign the variable or any other value to the cell.

```
a <- DF[DF1$Date ,names(DF2[2])] # works, stores value in a 

DF[DF1$Date ,names(DF2[2])] <- 2 # does not works. Gives error 
DF[DF1$Date ,names(DF2[1])] <-  a # does not work either. Same error
```

> Error in Summary.factor(20L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
>       ‘max’ not meaningful for factors
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In Ops.factor(i, 0L) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors

dput(head(DF2))

```
structure(list(B_Dryer.egaugekW = 1.9727155555,
 D_GroundSourceHeatPumpkW =   0. 603251389, 
 F_BasementkW = 0.30035222225), .Names = c("B_Dryer.egaugekW", 
 "D_GroundSourceHeatPumpkW", "F_BasementkW"), row.names = 1L, 
  class =   data.frame")
```

dput(head(DF1)) # subset of DF

dput(head(DF)) # its a year long data. Providing for the first row

```
"2016-12-27 12:00:00", "2016-12-27 13:00:00", "2016-12-27 14:00:00", 
"2016-12-27 15:00:00", "2016-12-27 16:00:00", "2016-12-27 17:00:00", 
"2016-12-27 18:00:00", "2016-12-27 19:00:00", "2016-12-27 20:00:00", 
"2016-12-27 21:00:00", "2016-12-27 22:00:00", "2016-12-27 23:00:00", 
"2016-12-28 00:00:00", "2016-12-28 01:00:00", "2016-12-28 02:00:00", 
"2016-12-28 03:00:00", "2016-12-28 04:00:00", "2016-12-28 05:00:00", 
"2016-12-31 21:00:00", "2016-12-31 22:00:00", "2016-12-31 23:00:00"
 ), class = "factor"), A_FurnaceHRVkW = 0.1052177775,
 A_CellarOutletskW =      0.0650380555, 
A_WashingMachinekW = 0.000536667, A_DuctHeaterHRVkW = 8.94445e-05, 
A_FridgeRangekW = 0.0009105555, A_DisposalDishwasherkW = 0.000260278, 
B_FurnacekW = 0.2270469445, B_Fridge.R.kW = 0.069405833, 
B_Dryer.egaugekW = 1.9727155555, B_UtilityRm.BasementBathkW =   0.0023033335, 
B_GarageoutletskW = 0.0048105555, C_Furnace1kW = 0.256180000016667, 
C_Furnace2kW = 0.24216361105, C_FridgekW = 0.14913916665, 
C_DishwasherkW = 8.58366833333333e-05, C_WinecellarkW = 0.00731083333333333, 
C_WellkW = 0.04181750005, C_BarnkW = 0.0479155555833333, 
C_GaragedoorkW = 0.0125686111, D_WashingMachinekW = 0.000705, 
D_WorkshopReceptacleBathHeaterkW = 0.071009444, D_GroundSourceHeatPumpkW = 0.603251389, 
D_WellPumpkW = 0.011735833, D_HeatCirculatorPumpskW = 0.02234, 
D_FreshAirVentilationkW = 0.0332, D_DryerkW = 8.67e-05, D_Basementamp.HallLightingkW = 0.0017075, 
D_BasementReceptacleskW = 0.003314722, D_GarageReceptaclesamp.LightskW = 0.000443333, 
D_GarageReceptacleskW = 0.028437222, D_GaragePVkW = 0.001769444, 
D_RefrigeratorkW = 0.032543611, F_FurnacekW = 0.108468889, 
F_WaterHeaterkW = 0.0029377775, F_WaterHeater3kW = 0.000782775, 
F_WaterHeater2kW = 0.00034222225, F_WaterHeater1kW = 0.00208833325, 
F_Dishwasher_DisposalkW = 0.0011105555, F_DryerkW = 0.00334722225, 
F_BasementkW = 0.30035222225, F_RefrigeratorkW = 0.089426111, 
G_WaterpumpkW = 0.007142778, G_EjectorpumpkW = 0.001268056, 
GridData = 5.85452975865), .Names = c("DateTime", "A_FurnaceHRVkW", 
"A_CellarOutletskW", "A_WashingMachinekW", "A_DuctHeaterHRVkW", 
 "A_FridgeRangekW", "A_DisposalDishwasherkW", "B_FurnacekW"
 ,   "B_Fridge.R.kW", 
 "B_Dryer.egaugekW", "B_UtilityRm.BasementBathkW", "B_GarageoutletskW", 
 "C_Furnace1kW", "C_Furnace2kW", "C_FridgekW", "C_DishwasherkW", 
 "C_WinecellarkW", "C_WellkW", "C_BarnkW", "C_GaragedoorkW"
  ,    "D_WashingMachinekW", "D_WorkshopReceptacleBathHeaterkW",
 "D_GroundSourceHeatPumpkW", "D_WellPumpkW", "D_HeatCirculatorPumpskW"
  ,       "D_FreshAirVentilationkW", "D_DryerkW"
  ,  "D_Basementamp.HallLightingkW", "D_BasementReceptacleskW",  
  "G_EjectorpumpkW", "GridData"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please share the output of `dput(head(DF1))` and `dput(head(DF2))` in the question summary. Also, the output of `dput(head(DF))`.

Comment: What you have provided for `DF` is incomplete output. If the data is too big try this: `dput(head(DF,2))`.

Comment: Even after using dput(head(DF,2)), the output is too long. The console doesn't even show the complete output.

Comment: Try this then: `dput(head(DF[,c(1:8)],2))`. We can omit some columns. That would not affect. Also, please share the same for `DF1`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got the answer by fetching the index of column and row.